# Recommend simple PHP Routing Engine

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, routes, fat-free-framework

Looking for simple php class routing, like this: http://fatfree.sourceforge.net/page/routing-engine

Is there a ready-made solutions? Or is it better to use the whole framework (it is lightweight, might even cut out the router)?

Comment: What have you linked to, if not a `ready-made solution`?

Comment: Routing Engine? its a small part. You can write it yourself by `mod_rewrite`. And improve it according to your need

Comment: @DaveRandom What I gave is the framework. But its use I have also seen, as a fallback. I would like to find a pure router class...

Comment: @Shiplu I know. But I do not want to "reinvent the wheel" or hardcode in the .htaccess.

Comment: Try pux, it's pretty simple and it's the fastest router right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) interesting. Otherwize if you only care about routing, using mod_rewrite is the most efficient solution.

Comment: Or just use the Routing bundle from symfony2 which is also used in Silex: https://github.com/symfony/Routing

Comment: It there any choice for PHP 5.1 ? (I know, we should upgrade, but everyone has a historical reason)

Answer (score 13):

You probably already found a solution but one of the routing classes I've been using lately are these two and they've proven to be effective.

PHPRouter.php https://github.com/dannyvankooten/PHP-Router
AltoRouter.php https://github.com/dannyvankooten/AltoRouter

Answer (score 0):

You might consider stripping down Zend Framework and only use the relevant parts, like:

- Application
- Router
- Front controller

However you will have to make it loose weight yourself, it works pretty nice!